# Android magnetometer sampling rate improvement/jitter reduction

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'd like to ask for some help regarding the sampling rate and jitter on the magnetometer.
I'm working on a project with some people that involves a high rate magnetic field sampling application. Even though we have developed an algorithm to workaround the jitter and other issues we encountered, we'd like to improve the sampling rating somehow and, at the same time, if possible, attempt to reduce the sampling jitter. Improving the sampling rate would allow us to achieve better results for our application. We are using a Samsung Nexus S and according to the tests we performed we observed that the sampling rates between 15ms and 20ms and, sometimes, peaks around 50 ms (this is between consecutive events).

We have come with different approaches to try to develop a solution to these issues, however without any success so far.
Firstly, we thought of modifying the current magnetometer (AK8973) device driver but we soon realized that the bottleneck couldn't the there as the device driver directly implements the correct sensor operation modes, data reading and respects the sensor hardware timing constraints.
As a second alternative, we developed a small code using Android NDK to obtain samples to compare the times obtained between consecutive events, i.e. between samples, with the code developed at the Java level. Sadly, the result was pretty much the same.
As a final alternative, we are currently trying to understand how the events are handled by the API and passed to Java. That said, if the bottleneck is there we'd try to change the code to solve the issues. However, we are not sure if the bottleneck is in the underlying hardware or software API.

The code we used for NDK is based on the example provided by the Android documentation (NativeActivity) and some other examples we came across with by googling (google groups and other articles). The articles we found are quite interesting ([Native Sampling](http://www.sensorplatforms.com/native-sampling), [Sensor Sampling Performance](http://www.sensorplatforms.com/smartphone-performance-fundamentals-sensor-sampling)). Even though it is reported that native sampling allows for better performance, in our case it seems not to happen.

We'd like to know if it is actually possible to obtain a higher sampling rate at all or if anyone has already developed a solution. Is the bottleneck at the software or hardware level?
In the articles referenced above, it is mentioned that a custom library (FreeMotion) is able to deliver better performance results, as a replace to the original sensor library, because it works with the drivers directly. Has anyone used this library before and, if yes, could you provide us your results?

Comment: You are trying to substitute a consumer level device for a piece of lab equipment. With everything else the phone is doing, your sample rates are actually impressive. Possibly you could investigate a device designed for your applicaiton connected by USB to the phone. You may want to investigate Arduino devices.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I see your point. If I understood you correctly, that suggests that the phone should be standing still. Even though that is one of our case scenarios, the phone should also be able move freely. Unfortunetely, since it is an application designed to the end consumer for a consumer level device, as you mentioned, we can't rely on anything else (other hardware platforms, etc.) and we are restricted to the smartphone capabilites.

Comment: Hmmmm. Can you root the phone and minimize the phone functions to the basic level. Connection with the network wi-fi and eliminate the junk tasks that vendors put in the background? You might go to the extreme of building an OS for a specific model phone...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and sorry for missing that detail. I could look into that, but the Wi-Fi must be available since it is required, as well, for our application.

Comment: Ooops. What I was saying was to eliminate anything possible except the Wi-Fi and Phone network. Things like background sync, vendor tracking, and other suchlike. I guess I don't really have more to contribute, so be safe, have fun, and good luck.

Comment: Again, thank you for your contribution. :)

Answer (score 1):

With another smartphone, a Samsung Galaxy Nexus, we decided to collect more magnetometer data samples and do some statistical analysis and compare the results obtained with the Samsung Nexus S. This time we used Android v4.1.2. Again, we observed that the rate at we are able to collect data does not improve significantly when comparing NDK vs SDK APIs with both smartphones, using the values from `ASensor_getMinDelay()` and `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`, respectively, which give maximum performance. The timestamp jitter reduction is, however, very significant for both smartphones with NDK API, regardless of the approach used: polling or callback-based. Polling, in general, provides little or no better results, and should be more CPU intensive.

The Samsung Galaxy Nexus sensor hardware is far superior, and thus fine-grained tuning of the desired event rate is possible for, naturally, rates aboves `ASensor_getMinDelay()`. For the Samsung Nexus S, however, this was not possible; for lower rates the target rate is not satisfied and samples are acquired at an even slower rate. Activating multiple sensors, the overall jitter reduction is greater than using only a single sensor.